# Delete post on my Facebook account using Java

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, facebook4j

I am using a `facebook4j` api for connecting to facebook.
My aim is to fetch and delete the posts posted on my wall by friends.
We are able to delete the posts taht are created by java code but unable to delete all other facebook posts on my profile created by friends.

-----Code that I tried--------------

```
ResponseList<Post> feed = facebook.getFeed();
facebook.deletePost(feed.get(0).getId());
```

---

Error is

```
errorType=OAuthException, errorMessage=(#200) This post wasn't created by the application, errorCode=200]
```

Comment: As far as my limited Facebook permission knowledge goes, you can't. The graph API docs state ["An app can delete a post if it published it:"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post#deleting).

Comment: But I want to delete it any how. Please suggest me the way to do so. Either suggest the way to hide it from other people. (It should only be visible to me) So later, I can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have added all the required permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have added all the required permissions. (read_insights,user_posts,read_stream)